# tables export into to csv files

Tags: php, laravel, csv

In laravel 5.5 project I want some my tables export into to csv files and I get this http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#export library
with code like:

```
$path = $directoriesArray[count($directoriesArray)-1];
Excel::create($filename, function($excel) use($dataArray) {
    $excel->sheet('file', function($sheet)  use($dataArray) {
        $sheet->fromArray( $dataArray );
    });
})->store('csv', $path)->export('csv');
```

I upload 1 file ok, but as I need to upload several tables any 
to the relative file I run the exporting function in a circle 
and only the first file is uploaded. Is it restriction of the 
browser(I tried in chromium, firefox) or if is the way to upload all files?

1) If there is a way just to write this csv file to disk without uploading?

2) If there is some way to make kind of buffering ( like ﻿ob_start ) of output data and write them to the files manually?

3) If there is some other tools that could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: could you share your code from the loop, also the code that handles the upload

Answer (score 1):

The decision was :

```
})->store('csv', $path);
```

without

```
->export('csv')
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like :

```
<?php


$tablesArray= [  // array of tables to export
    'settings',
    'groups',
    'users',
];
$now_label= '_1';//strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S');
$directories= [ public_path('uploads'), public_path('uploads/csv') , public_path('uploads/csv/loan_dump_'.$now_label) ];// to which directory export files
foreach( $tablesArray as $next_key=>$next_table_name ) {  // all tables
    $columnListing= \Schema::getColumnListing( $next_table_name );  // table columns

    if ( $next_table_name == 'settings' ) {
        $dataRows = Settings::all();
    }
    if ( $next_table_name == 'groups' ) {
        $dataRows = Group::all();
    }
    if ( $next_table_name == 'users' ) {
        $dataRows = User::all();
    }
    if ($dataRows == null) {
        die("-1 XXZ INVALID DATA");
    }
    $dataRowsArray = $dataRows->toArray();

    $writeRowsArray= [];
    $row= 0;
    foreach( $dataRowsArray as $next_key=>$nextDataRow ) {
        if (!empty($nextDataRow['created_at'])) {
            $nextDataRow['created_at'] = $this->dateTimeToDbFormat($nextDataRow['created_at']);
        }
        if (!empty($nextDataRow['updated_at'])) {
            $nextDataRow['updated_at'] = $this->dateTimeToDbFormat($nextDataRow['updated_at']);
        }
        if ($row == 0) { // first row with keys/file headers
            $writeRowsArray[] = $nextDataRow;
        } else {
            $writeRowsArray[] = array_values($nextDataRow);
        }
        $row++;
    }
    $this->writeArrayToCsvFile($writeRowsArray, $next_table_name, $directories);

} // foreach( $tablesArray as $next_key=>$next_table_name ) {  // all tables

public function writeArrayToCsvFile(array $dataArray, string $filename, array $directoriesArray) : int
{
    self::createDir(  $directoriesArray  );
    $path = $directoriesArray[count($directoriesArray)-1];
    Excel::create($filename, function($excel) use($dataArray) {
        $excel->sheet('file', function($sheet)  use($dataArray) {
            $sheet->fromArray( $dataArray );
        });
    })->store('csv', $path)->export('csv');
    return 1;
}


?>
```

Only 1st file in $tablesArray array is exported ok.
If to comment 1st table, then next table would uploaded ok and so on.

What is strange file is uploaded twice : in $directories path and in "Downloads" directory(I am under kubuntu).